# How to fix typos in a column using R? [SOLVED]

Tags: r, dataframe

EDIT: **Wow**, so it turns out I spent the last hour trying completely correct methods but not paying any attention whatsoever to the case. That is, the strings I was trying to change are all uppercase and I was inputting them as sentence case. Don't be like me!

let's say I have a column in my data frame called "Food group" and it looks like this:

```
[1] "Grains"     "Grains"     "Proteins"   "Proteins"   "Vegetables"
[6] "Dairy"      "Fruits"     "Fruiits"
```

I need to change the "Fruiits" to "Fruits".

My actual dataframe has thousands of observations, but a similar column of "categories" with an extra redundant category (like Fruiits instead of Fruits) because of a typo, leading us to under count the frequency of that particular category. For instance, we have 300 instances of "Fruits" and 200 of "Fruiits", rather than just 500 of "Fruits".

I tried using gsub and stringr to fix this but it doesn't seem like my commands are doing anything whatsoever. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `gsub` with `fixed` argument to `TRUE` to disable regex

```
t <- c("Grains", "Grains" , "Proteins" ,"Proteins" ,"Vegetables", "Dairy" , "Fruits" , "Fruiits" )

gsub("Fruiits"  , "Fruits" , t , fixed = TRUE)
```

- output

```
[1] "Grains"     "Grains"     "Proteins"   "Proteins"  
[5] "Vegetables" "Dairy"      "Fruits"     "Fruits"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized that I was not accounting for case sensitivity. My code now works.